# How to end while loop in Java

Tags: java, loops

I am coding in JAVA and I am trying to figure out how to end while loops with a simple method which I'm trying to use for advanced codes. To test out if it works, I made this code:

```
package files;

public class EndLoopWithBooleanMethod {
    static boolean a = true;
    public static void main(String[] args){

        while(a = true){
            EndLoop(a);
            System.out.print(".");
            EndLoop(a);
        }
    }

    public static boolean EndLoop(boolean b){
        return false;
    }

}
```

When I create it, it will just keep on printing the .'s even though it is supposed to return false and end the loop, I have tried changing the

```
static boolean a = true;
```

to

```
static boolean a;
```

but see no difference.

I know that you can end a loop with `break`; but I'm not trying that, for I can use methods to end loops efficiently in a different context. Please correct me by showing my original line(s) of code, and then showing me the fixed one, it helps me understand more (explain it too).

EDIT: ANSWER SOLVED, MOST PEOPLE HAD SAME/CORRECT ANSWER: NO NEED FOR MORE ANSWERS!

Comment: What do you think a `return` statement does? What is the difference between `=` and `==`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't change the value of a (which is true by default) to false, you just call a method that will return false but nothing is set to this returned value.

Change your code to this:

```
package files;

public class EndLoopWithBooleanMethod {
static boolean a = true;
public static void main(String[] args){

    while(a) {    //This is enough as a is a boolean, the complete thing would be
                  //whlie (a == true)
        EndLoop(a);
        System.out.print(".");
        EndLoop(a);
    }
}

public static void EndLoop(boolean var){
    var = false;  //a is set to false instead of the method returning false
}
}
```

Comment: This also helps my problem in a full code way, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assign return value of method to `boolean a`

Try this one:

```
while(a == true){
        a=EndLoop(a);
        System.out.print(".");
       a= EndLoop(a);
    }
```

`a=true` will assign value of a to true even though you are returning false. Instead use `a==true`

Answer (score 1):

First issue: `while(a = true)` is always true. You need to use comparison: `while(a == true)` and because `a` is a boolean you would write it just as:

```
while(a)
```

The second issue: `EndLoop` doesn't do anything. The parameter seems useless as Java is not pass by reference. The return value is useless unless you do something with the value. My guess is you want something like this:

```
public static void endLoop(){
    a = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `while(a = true)` is not a compare operator. You need to change it to `while(a == true)`.

Having `a = true` sets `a` equal to `true`. What you really mean is "if (a is equal to true)" which is `a == true`. (Since this is boolean, you can just condense it to `while(a)`)

So for you:

```
while(a){
        EndLoop(a);
        System.out.print(".");
        EndLoop(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
package files;

public class EndLoopWithBooleanMethod {
    static boolean[] a = new boolean[1];
    public static void main(String[] args){

        while(a[0] == false){
            EndLoop(a);
            System.out.print(".");
            EndLoop(a);
        }
    }

    public static void EndLoop(boolean[] b){
        b[0] = true;
    }
}
```

The problem is that arguments are passed by value, so if you want to change them you can do the above trick - create a reference to them by putting them in an array, so then the array reference itself won't change, just the value it contains.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up some things:

- You're not checking if `a` is `true`, but setting it. Use a single equals sign (`=`) for an assignment of a value to a variable, and a double equals operator (`==`) for a comparison.

  `while (a = true)` must be `while (a == true)` or just `while (a)`
- In the method `EndLoop(boolean a)`, you're taking one parameter, but you don't do anything with the parameter. You're just returning `false`, leaving the `a` argument unused.

  You should write something like this:

  ```
  static boolean a = true;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      while (a == true) { // Or "while (a)", which is the same
          System.out.print(".");
          a = endLoop();
          // a will be false
          // and there will be no next iteration of the while loop,
          // because a is not true anymore
      }
  }

  public static boolean endLoop(/* We don't need arguments here */) {
      return false;
  }
  ```

May I also do a few suggestions:

- You should start a method name with a lowercase letter, see the Java Naming Conventions.
- Calling a method `endLoop()` where you only return `false` is useless, you should use `break` in the `while` loop. If you want to extend the `endLoop()` method with some variable checking, you should rename `endLoop`.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loops as any other conditional loop in Java accepts a `boolean` value as a condition, so you can pass in simply your `a` boolean primitive:

```
while(a){
    EndLoop(a); //This will reassign the a primitive with a false literal
    System.out.print(".");
}
```

What you was actually doing, is reassinging the `true` literal to the `a` variable, and checking on it, so obviousely it will be true for ever and you will end up with an endless loop.

The second case to check, is your `EndLoop` method (pay attention to method naming, first letter should be lowercase) that should be updated by either taking an argument an updating its value:

```
public static boolean endLoop(boolean b){
    b = false; //It will update the a value when it is passed as an argument
}
```

Or just don't pass in any arguments and change the `a` literal value since it is a class instance:

```
public static boolean endLoop(){
    a = false;
}
```